#  getting next value in android using SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have doing small application in android.During this application, i have suffer this problem:

I search the keyword using "**oh**" then i listing in to listview using this code.

```
nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this,
                        SearchDetails.class);
                /*
                 * Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
                 * intent.putExtra("JOK_ID",
                 * cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                 */
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                Log.d(TAG, " I.." + id);
                Log.d(TAG, " P.." + position);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

for example like this [image]

Now, if I click **oham** then display just like this: [image]

Finally, I want to , If i click previous button then display **john** and Next to display **krackohm**. And count total number of searched names.
I have try this code for next button:

```
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM std WHERE _id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+Id});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        
            ...body 
                    
        }
```

**Edit:**

This is first time when any list item click, on create

```
 private void dislpayFirstName() { // this is display first time click list item
     writeDatabase();
     cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM std WHERE._id = ?", 
            new String[]{""+Id});

        if (cursor.getCount()> 0)

        {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        nameDetails();
        }
}
```

This is the code for Next Button click:

```
        position++; 
        writeDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,name FROM std", null);
        if (cursor.getCount()> 0)
        {
           cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            //cursor.moveToNext();
        nameDetails();                  
        }
```

In next button: If  **cursor.moveToPosition(position);** then next name display matching position and table id. Means postion 2 then display 2 number name from table.

In next button: If  **cursor.moveToNext();** then next name display  beginning of table.Means 0 id name from table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM std") // get all rows
```

Than, to display you first entry:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
displayData();  // Method to display the data from the cursor on screen
```

Clicking you "next" Button:

```
if (cursor.moveToNext()){ // moveToNext returns true if there is a next row
displayData();}
```

And equally: with your "previous"Button use `cursor.moveToPrevious()`

Comment: you are talking about whole database named std, its ok -  its work fine, but I am talking about the searched items means selected items.So how to used for searched item used this.Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM std where name="john"); this named john has id>> 5, 8 , 12, 13. so how to display this.

Comment: Exactly like you said: "SELECT _id, name FROM std WHERE name=\"john\"". Than your Cursor will have all rows with name="john". With moveToNext or moveToFirst you can move between the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Put `cursor.moveToFirst();` at first. I mean put it like this..

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
if(your condition)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id as extra with intent,you should use the position of the item in list.

The position will be similar to the position of the same record in your cursor so you just need to move your cursor to that position and fetch the detail you need from the same.Then you can display it on activity,as you have shown on your second activity view.

so in your SearchDetails.class,you need to do:

```
    ...
    int position=getIntent.getIntExtra("position",999); // 999 is default value
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(<query which you fired for populating search results in previous activity>);    
   if (cursor.getCount()> 0 && position!=999){

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);    
        ...body  // fetch details and display it.
   }
   backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

               position--;
               //display details code
               Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(<query which you fired for populating search results in previous activity>);    
               if (cursor.getCount()> 0 && position!=-1){

                     cursor.moveToPosition(position);    
                     ...body  // fetch details and display it.
               }
        }
   }
   nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

               position++;
               //display details code
               Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(<query which you fired for populating search results in previous activity>);    
               if (cursor.getCount()> 0 && position!=cursor.getCount()){

                    cursor.moveToPosition(position)    
                    ...body  // fetch details and display it.
               }
       }
 }
 ...
```

**EDIT :**

Revised code: ( repeated code removed)

```
...
        int position=getIntent.getIntExtra("position",999); // 999 is default value
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(<query which you fired for populating search results in previous activity>);        
       if (cursor.getCount()> 0 && position!=999){

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);        
            ...body  // fetch details and display it.
       }
       backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   position--;    
                   if (position!=-1){

                         cursor.moveToPosition(position);        
                         ...body  // fetch details and display it.
                   }
       }
       nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   position++;                       
                   if (position!=cursor.getCount()){

                        cursor.moveToPosition(position)        
                        ...body  // fetch details and display it.
                   }
           }
     }
     ...
```

Comment: cursor.moveTo(position); may be this line something wrong,  check it.

Comment: Sorry,it was a mistake.please check my edited answer.Please follow the code under "EDIT :"

Comment: it is ok for first time click any of the list item, but if i click next then doesn't show next name according to list. If I click next then position may be 5 then show id 5 according to database table rather then on a list. check my Edit question.

Comment: I didn't get whats your problem with this code!? i can surely help if you explain bit more.

Comment: And why do you still want to use id there? it can be solved just by using position,nothing else is really required.i saw your edited question.your both queries are differnt AFAIK.

Comment: Here Id is used for, When click first time of list of searched item then display according to its id not position.I dont understand about if i am using position then it display accorading to position id. if if am first click of list then display not first position of list item , it display first id of table. .....So How to query search item ? i am  so big confused?

Comment: I did not understand your second line, where  how to query >> Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(<query which you fired for populating search results in previous activity>); in my code i am using table id, but you told me replacing id with position, am i right?? so how to query? i am waiting for your response?

Comment: I didn't tell you to use position to fire query.The query which you fire for searching items from database according to search string,the same you need to use for getting various listitems to be displayed in larger view,in another activity.In that another class,you need to use list position to get correct item to be displayed in larger view,and not table id.